# Webgility Unify Order API error - attempt to dereference a null object reference

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am attempting to use the [Unify Order API](https://github.com/webgility/Unify-APIs/wiki/Orders-API) to code against [Webgility](https://www.webgility.com). I am using

I have used sample request data and [php code](https://github.com/webgility/Unify-APIs/wiki/Orders-API) and added my token

```
 $url = 'https://unify.webgility.com/api/api/Orders';
 $Token='XXXXXXX';
 $data = '{
  "Orders": {
    "OrderId": "1010",
    "OrderDate": "2014-08-20",
    "Customer": {
      "FirstName": "Dan",
      "LastName": "Scheffler",
      "CompanyName": "ABC Corp.",
      "EmailAddress": "dans@abc.com"
    },
    "BillingAddress": {
      "FirstName": "Webgility",
      "LastName": "Inc",
      "AddressLine1": "2703 Town Center Lane",
      "AddressLine2": "Add2",
      "AddressLine3": "Add3",
      "AddressLine4": "Add4",
      "City": "Sunnyvale",
      "Region": "South",
      "PostalCode": "940862",
      "Country": "US"
    },
    "ShippingAddress": {
      "FirstName": "Dan",
      "LastName": "Scheffler",
      "AddressLine1": "511 Willson Lane",
      "AddressLine2": "Add2",
      "AddressLine3": "Add3",
      "AddressLine4": "AAA",
      "City": "Franklin",
      "Region": "Central",
      "PostalCode": "85061",
      "Country": "US"
    },
    "OrderItems": [
      {
        "SKU": "Book1",
        "Name": "Novel Book 1",
        "Description": "Qwertyuiop",
        "UnitPrice": 10,
        "UnitCost": 5,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Taxable": false
      },
      {
        "SKU": "Book2",
        "Name": "Tech Book 2",
        "Description": "WE22222",
        "UnitPrice": 10,
        "UnitCost": 5,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Taxable": false
      }
    ],
    "ShipmentStatus": "Shipped",
    "ShipmentMethod": "FedEx",
    "ShipmentCarrier": "Overnight",
    "ShippingCharges": 10,
    "ShippingCost": 10,
    "TotalDiscounts": 5,
    "TotalTax": 5,
    "TotalAmount": 30,
    "PaymentStatus": "Paid",
    "PaymentMethod": "Check",
    "PaymentNotes": "My Payment",
    "Notes": "My Notes",
    "Currency": "USD"
  }
 }';

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30000); //timeout after 30 seconds
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $Token);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Content-Type: application/json',
 'Token: ' . $Token
 ));
 $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  // 0 
 $result=curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
```

The result message always returns:

```
An  
Please contact Support: support@webgility.com or (877) 753-5373 ext.3
```

Webgility support is barely aware they have an API and my attempts to reach a dev were unsuccessful - evidently they don't speak english at all. Anyone ever use this "service"?

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`. I think it's doing a GET. I have no experience with these APIs or services, just an observation.

Comment: Good though but it is sending as POST it turns out. Here's from the curl docs: `Using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS implies setting CURLOPT_POST to 1.`